# Google Insights - JavaScript loading optimization

Tags: javascript, optimization, firebug, pageload

I have a problem with optimizing my page load time. I moved my script code at end of the page, but I still have a problem with rendering blocking the download of the JavaScript files.

I checked my site in Firebug and I get this:
[image: JavaScript resources blocked by page rendering]

Why is my code loaded before images and other elements within the page if that code is included at the end of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the load time of the page request (the first one in the list) takes ~1.5 seconds - more precisely the server response time - which delays all the other requests.

So regarding the graph you need to check why the server needs that long to process the page request.

*Note that the page request returns the HTML of the page, which then needs to be parsed first. And after it is parsed, the other requests are started.*